# Calculating smallest postive floating point number

Tags: floating-point, binary, scientific-notation, data-representation

A 16-bit floating point representation is defined like this: 1 bit for sign, 6 bits for exponent and 9 bits for significand. Floating point number must be normalized (in the form 0.1... × 2exp). Exponent is stored in one’s complement representation. Significand is stored as is without any hidden bits. Find out the smallest positive number that can be stored in such a system. Work out its (i) 16 bit binary (ii) equivalent base 10 number in scientific notation.

How would I calculate this? From my understanding to show the smallest possible positive number in normalised form in this system we can set the first bit of our exponent to 1. This is because our exponent is stored in one’s complement form so the first bit will have the greatest negative value possible ie -32. For the significand/mantissa it must be in normalised form with a leading 01 and all other bits set to 0 to achieve the smallest possible value.

This gives me 0 100000 010000000.

Is this correct or am I totally doing this wrong?

To convert back to decimal should I be doing 2^(-32)  ×0.010000000 if it's normalised as 0.1...x2^exp?

Comment: In one’s complement, 100000 is −31, not −32.

Comment: If there are no hidden bits and the representation is normalized to have a significand 0.xxxxxxxxx, then typically only the xxxxxxxxx bits would be stored. The leading 0 would not be considered a hidden bit as it never changes and so is really just part of the specification, not part of the significand proper. Then, if the significand must be normalized, the smallest significand is represented by bits 100000000.

Comment: That format is odd because it leaves no way to represent zero, unless perhaps the −0 exponent (111111) is used for it.

Comment: So from 0 100000 100000000, I would calculate the base 10 equivalent in scientific notation as 2^(-31)x0.100000000?

Comment: Yes, given the description in the posted question.